# Three.js change material

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to select my geometry with the numbers on my keyboard, like this:

```
if(keyboard.pressed("1")){
   obj = torus;
}
```

so i can show/no show them:

```
if(keyboard.pressed("a")){
   THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy( obj, function ( obj ) { obj.visible = false; } );
}
```

I would like to change the material (or the color) of that "selected geometry" so i can see which is selected.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obj.material.color.setHex( 0xffff00 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only problem now is that if I run this code all my models are changed ( I have 6 of them ). Is it possible to change only one of them?

Comment: Is it possible to change the material of that obj because I also use wireframe and the color is changed there, too.

Comment: That's because you're sharing the same material in all of them. Try creating a material for each.

Comment: I did this but now my problem is that the wireframe is gone and when I do `obj.material.wireframe.setHex(0xffffff)` there is no white wireframe only the one of the "selected" color before.

Comment: uh... where did you get the wireframe thing from? try just with the code in my answer...

Comment: I tried on my own .. when I do your answer the wireframe is gone and with this line the wireframe still is there. I already fixed the problem by not using an for-loop. But is there any possibility to change the whole material, because now I have a material for every object and later I would like to have some thousand objects so it would be easyer to change the material.